# Отправляя письма через форму на сайте, письма приходят с неверной кодировкой

Tags: email, php, sendmail

Здравствуйте! 
Написал простенький скрипт обратной формы на `php + jquary`.
Сам скрипт с функцией `mail()`:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
$sug = strip_tags($_POST['sug']);

echo "Ваше Ф.И.О.       :".$name."</br>";   
echo "Ваш контактный телефон        :".$email."</br>";  
echo "Время и дата      :".$sug."</br>";    
echo "<span class=\"label label-info\" >Ваш запрос отправлен. Спасибо вам за ваш интерес к нашей компании!</span>";

$from = 'test@mail.ru';
$emailTo = 'test@mail.ru';
$subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode('Запрос прайс листа с сайта: test').'?=';
$headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';
$headers .= "From: ". $from ." <". $from ."> \r\n";  
$body = "Ф.И.О. контактного лица: $name \n\nКонтактный телефон клиента: $email \n\nВремя и дата удобное для звонка ему:\n $sug";

$headers = 'C сайта: test <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Отправитель: ' . $name . "\r\n" ;
$headers .= "Date: ". date('D, d M Y h:i:s O') ."\r\n";

mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $from );

$emailSent = true;
}?>
```

В данном скрипте проблему с заголовком письма решил, если письмо отправляю на локальном сервере в denwer и читаю их в Thunderbird то с кодировкой проблем нет, как только выложил его на виртуальный сервак и отправил письмо на почтовый ящик размещенный на mail.ru, появляются крокозябры:

```
C я│п╟п╧я┌п╟: test <test@mail.ru>
п·я┌п©я─п╟п╡п╦я┌п╣п╩я▄: я┌п╣я│я┌п╦я─п╬п╡п╟п╫п╦п╣
Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2013 11:03:16 +0400

п╓.п≤.п·. п╨п╬п╫я┌п╟п╨я┌п╫п╬пЁп╬ п╩п╦я├п╟: я┌п╣я│я┌п╦я─п╬п╡п╟п╫п╦п╣

п п╬п╫я┌п╟п╨я┌п╫я▀п╧ я┌п╣п╩п╣я└п╬п╫ п╨п╩п╦п╣п╫я┌п╟: я┌п╣я│я┌п╦я─п╬п╡п╟п╫п╦п╣

п▓я─п╣п╪я▐ п╦ п╢п╟я┌п╟ я┐п╢п╬п╠п╫п╬п╣ п╢п╩я▐ п╥п╡п╬п╫п╨п╟ п╣п╪я┐:
 я┌п╣я│я┌п╦я─п╬п╡п╟п╫п╦п╣
```

Тема письма отображается верно.

Прошу помощи разобраться в данной проблеме.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну как бы все пользуются для почты http://phpmailer.worxware.com/. Но в вашем случаи есть прям в документации ответ http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php :

```
        function mail_utf8($to, $subject = '(No subject)', $message = '', $from) {
  $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
    . "\n" . 'From: Yourname <' . $from . ">\n";
  mail($to, '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=', $message, $header);
}
```

Comment: как видно из вашего скрипта вам надо поменять utf-8 на UTF-8

Comment: пробовал в своем скрипте поменять utf-8 на UTF-8 результат аналогичен.
попробую выше описанный вами пример и отпишусь о результатах.

Comment: спасибо за наводку помогло)

Answer (score 3):

У меня тоже тело письма отправляло кракозябрами. Декодером лебедева проверил - оказалось что кракозябры в кодировке KOI8-R. Помог код преобразования KOI8-R в UTF-8. Сама страничка у меня в кодировке UTF-8.

```
$mes = "Номер телефона: $tele"; /*Тело письма, которое неправильно отображалось*/
$in_charset = "KOI8-R";
$out_charset = "UTF-8"; 
iconv ($in_charset, $out_charset, $mes); /*Преобразуем*/
$send = mail($address, $sub, $mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8" );
```

Comment: Если ваша страничка в кодировке UTF-8, то каким образом текст приходит на сервер в кодировке KOI8-R? Похоже где-то в настройках сервера, стоит кодировка KOI8-R. А Вы свои скриптовые файлы надеюсь в кодировке "UTF-8 без BOM" сохраняете?