# Кодировка письма в PHP c помощью mail()

Tags: php, email

```
$message = "Модель: " . $_POST['model'] . "\r\n ФИО: " . $_POST['fio'] ;
  if (mail("mail@mail.ru", "Subj", $message,
            "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n"
            . "Reply-To: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n"
            . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()))
            echo 1;
```

**Приходит текст в таком формате:**

> Comment: ааОбаА аПаЕбаЕббаАбб аДаЕаЛаИбб аМаЕббаО аНаА
>   баЕбаВаЕбаЕ! ааАб, аИ баОаЛбаКаО аВаАб баЕбаВаЕб
>   баЕаЛаИаКаОаМ.

Comment: Попробуйте в `headers` прописать "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/231080/186083

Comment: http://webew.ru/articles/297.webew

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `header` при отправке и конкретно укажите `UTF-8`

```
 $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
mail($email, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```